# Overflow Scroll box moves divs left and right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I am not an advanced coder and I am struggling with making these two overflow boxes move the div lines left and right, I tried with using this existing code: http://jsfiddle.net/pWUDJ/275/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
$("div#mydiv").css({
    "right": $(window).scrollTop() + "px"
}).text("hello:"+$(window).scrollTop());
```

});

My code Is —  http://jsfiddle.net/millington/6v1fc7bj/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
$("div#l2").css({
    "right": $("#leftscr").scrollTop() + "px"
}).text("left&right:"+$("#leftscr").scrollTop());
```

});

Please Help If you can ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var div_offset  = $("#leftscr").offset().top;
var window_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

var scroll = (1- (div_offset - window_scroll)/div_offset) * 100;
if(scroll < 100) {
    $("div#l2").css({
        "left": scroll + "%"
    }).text("left&right:"+scroll + "%");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6v1fc7bj/1/

if required in px

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var div_offset  = $("#leftscr").offset().top;
var window_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if(window_scroll < div_offset) {
    $("div#l2").css({
        "left": window_scroll + "px"
    }).text("left&right:"+window_scroll + "px");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6v1fc7bj/2/

Comment: Thank you for your help but it is still only moving when the page is scrolled and not when the overflow box is